# Firefox OS app beginner, can't import localforage properly : Could not find module `ember-localforage-adapter/adapters/localforage`

Tags: ember.js, bower, ember-cli, firefox-os, localforage

I'm currently learning how to develop a new app in Firefox OS, following step-by-step the MDN tutorial starting here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Modern_web_app_architecture

Everything went pretty smoothly until the part concerning the Model, here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Modern_web_app_architecture/Models_and_application_data

Specifically at the point of installing LocalForage.

I tried the first :

```
ember install:addon ember-localforage-adapter
```

And got the error message described in the tutotrial, so I tried the other command `bower install localforage -v '1.2.2'`
It just returned the bower version.

So I tried `bower install localforage` alone and it worked. I got the new folder in myapp/bower_components/localforage.

The tutorial next gives the instruction to use the code :

```
import LFAdapter from 'ember-localforage-adapter/adapters/localforage';

export default LFAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'ShoppingLists'
});
```

Here is where I'm stuck. I got the error message :

> Error while processing route: lists.index Could not find module 'ember-localforage-adapter/adapters/localforage' imported from `'myapp/adapters/application'
>   requireFrom@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:119:1

I didn't get the logic behind the import call, no ember-local-forage-adapter folder or something similar. I'm not comfortable with namespaces yet, but I know the theory.
Is there a namespace problem somewhere I can't recognize ? Is it related to ember-data ?

I can give the full error message, but I'm pretty sure that won't help.

I did my best to figure it out alone, but I ran out of ideas, so I'm asking here.

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, that seems pretty trivial now, but as I found some similar subjects across the interweb, I'm gonna share it.

Run the additional command :

```
ember install ember-localforage-adapter
```

Now it works, at least I don't have the error message, and I can move on in the tutorial.